# Reset to ALAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined on device

Tags: ios, ios6, alassetslibrary

Is there a way to reset a device versus an app so `ALAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` is returned for `[ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus]`?

Deleting the app and reinstalling does not help.

Comment: What parts of it is unclear? If you ever used `authorizationStatus` I think you would know what I mean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset ALAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined for photo permission on real device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698943/how-to-reset-alauthorizationstatusnotdetermined-for-photo-permission-on-real-dev)

Comment: Yep. Exact duplicate. Answer in that post is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21699126/1226095