# How to reset ALAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined for photo permission on real device

Tags: ios, permissions

In detail,

I am making a photo function for my app, it seems that when I permit the app to access the photo once, ALAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined will no longer appear again, even I have deleted the app.

So is there any way that I can reset the app ALAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined again for debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When developing on real device, reset privacy settings in

> Setting, General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy

Be aware that this will reset the settings for all applications at once.